# Using for-loop variable in awk print

Tags: shell, for-loop, awk

I'm trying to print out

```
for i in 0.80 0.85 0.90 0.95 1.00 1.05 1.10 1.15 1.20 1.25 1.30 1.35 1.40; do
awk -v a="$i" '{printf "%10.2f %10.2f\n", a, ($8*627.509)}' e1.txt > e2.txt
done
```

But when I open this file,

```
  1.40 -12111939.85
  1.40 -12112479.17
  1.40 -12112817.98
  1.40 -12112997.55
  1.40 -12113047.39
  1.40 -12112998.93
  1.40 -12112873.57
  1.40 -12112695.74
  1.40 -12112504.02
  1.40 -12112346.74
  1.40 -12112316.49
  1.40 -12112204.51
  1.40 -12112149.56
```

Ignore the second column as it reads the value and operates from other txt file, e1.txt.

As it is shown, only the last for-loop index variable is used in this case. But I wish to print the for-loop values of 0.80 ~ 1.40 accordingly to each line.

Comment: Your output redirection overwrites the output file for every iteration of the loop. Remove the output redirection from the "awk" line and add it to the "done" line: `done > e2.txt`

Comment: change `>` to `>>` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For efficiency, I would avoid processing the same file 13 times.

The BEGIN block looks awkward because awk can't declare an array literal.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    a = "0.80 0.85 0.90 0.95 1.00 1.05 1.10 1.15 1.20 1.25 1.30 1.35 1.40"
    n = split(a, as)
  }
  {
    for (i=1; i <= n; i++)
      printf "%10.2f %10.2f\n", as[i], ($8 * 627.509)
  }
' e1.txt > e2.txt
```

If you want all the `0.80` first and all the `1.40` last, you can:

```
awk '...' e1.txt | sort -g > e2.txt
```

Comment: you could just do `split("0.80 0.85 ...", as)` though, no need for `a`.